# Azure - Server failed to authenticate the request when trying to get blobs list

Tags: azure

Good day,
could you please help me to get the answer on the following question?

I'm trying to get the list of the blobs from the specific container using zaure cli v1. Here is the steps I'm following:

```
1) azure login
2) Login via browser
3) from the command line: azure storage blob list \ 
--container "container_name" -a "storage_account_name" -k $(cat ./storage_account_name.key)
```

storage_account_name.key - has the actual access key for the storage account.
When I'm running that command from the cli, I'm getting the following error:

```
info:    Executing command storage blob list
|error:   Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of 
Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:<ID of the request>
Time:2017-08-18T13:34:53.3484100Z
error:   Error information has been recorded to /root/.azure/azure.err
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list blobs in your storage account, you need firstly set two variables for your storage account and key.

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=<storage_account_name>
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=<storage_account_key>
```

Please refer to this [link:Using the Azure CLI 1.0 with Azure Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli-nodejs).

Update:

Your command works for me.

```
root@shui:~# azure storage blob list --container "vhds" -a "shuihvdiag182" -k $(cat ./storage_account_name.key)
info:    Executing command storage blob list
+ Getting blobs in container vhds
data:    Name                Blob Type  Length  Content Type              Last Modified                  Snapshot Time
data:    ------------------  ---------  ------  ------------------------  -----------------------------  -------------
data:    Availabilityset.sh  BlockBlob  1180    application/octet-stream  Tue, 22 Aug 2017 02:13:01 GMT
info:    storage blob list command OK
```

I configure `storage_account_name.key` like below:

```
aj5tKjaWBCGemBJ+gEmlCFLNP+/1zNgwuPDE+dDkKCXjoRCgdggmwCNDZheMmK8+gRiHUS+qR7NMkWfx5n8tjw==
```

I suggest you could check storage account key whether expired. I suggest you could regenerate a key and try again.

Update 2:

I meet same error log when I use error access key. You don't need login your Azure account, use `storage account name`+ `access key` could list blobs in container. I suggest you could check them on Portal.

[image]

Comment: but I have specified account name and storage access key by the flags in the CLI:

azure storage blob list \ 
--container "container_name" \ 
-a "storage_account_name" \ 
-k $(cat ./storage_account_name.key)

really doubting this is an issue...

Comment: @AlexMiroshnik Sorry for my mistake, your command works for me. I suggest you could check your storage key, if possible, I suggest you could regenerate a new key and test again.

Comment: @AlexMiroshnik Hi, do you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, still have the same issue. I will try to play with subscriptions (i have more than one) and storage account keys. But I'm 99% sure I'm using the right ones. I will open ticket with MS if I can't solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: @AlexMiroshnik You don't need login Azure subscription. Use `storage account`+`key` could list blobs in the containers. I meet your issue when I use unmatch key. Please ensure your key is right.

Comment: @AlexMiroshnik Hi, do you solve this issue?

Comment: nope. Checked storage account + key twice, all looks fine. Escalated the issue further up in organisation. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @AlexMiroshnyk It is very strange. Your storage account is a classic account or arm account? If possible, could you try `export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=<storage_account_name>
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=<storage_account_key>` and use `azure storage blob list $container_name` to list blobs.

Comment: @ Walter - MSFT I have re-created the storage account and changed storage account name and key in the script and now all works perfectly fine. Thank you very much for support

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer has very little to do with what I have done to make it working. You have suggested to define storage account name and storage account key as the variables, which is wrong answer as I used CLI flags to define them. It started working after I re-create the account. I do not want to confuse anybody there fore I can't mark your answer is the right one.